# SSRS 2005 formatting question

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I am working on SSRS 2005. I am using two rows as header. The border between the two rows are made white color. The report works fine when I generate it with report viewer.

However, when I export it to PDF, the hidden (i.e, white) lines become visible (in black). Is there any way to rectify it?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the colour none/nothing instead and setting border style to none/nothing?